# Python Client/Server to stream logfile updates in realtime?

Tags: python, streaming, twisted, logfiles, solaris-10

We have applications on Solaris 10 servers that generate text logfiles. We need to stream these logfiles in realtime to a central server for monitoring of new events.

Ideally we'd have a NFS-mount, and all our system would write their logs to there, and the monitoring server could just pull them up from there. Unfortunately, for technical and non-technical reasons that's not an option here.

At the moment, we're using a backgrounded tail -f to pipe the data over an SSH tunnel.

However, we were looking at whether it's worth putting together something a bit more robust.

I was thinking of writing a simple Python client/server with Twistedb (or something similar - recommendations?) to stream the log data. Is this something that's easily achievable? Any existing libraries/tools I could look to for ideas? Any issues I should be aware of?

Also, this is Solaris 10, so I'm not familiar with the state of filesystem monitors. I do know Gamin is available via OpenCSW. however, are there any other choices out there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out Python's logging module. http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html

It contains the capability to log to files, streams, syslog, networked servers, and more. The cookbook contains examples or logging over the network. http://docs.python.org/howto/logging-cookbook.html#logging-cookbook

The module is fairly easy to extend also.

Comment: Hmm, that's quite an interesting approach. First question - the application generating the logfiles isn't in Python (it's in C++), and I suspect we don't have the source. How would I get Python logging to read in those logfiles, and read in new lines as they come in? Second question - Am I better off using the inbuilt SocketServer, rather than a framework like Twisted? To be honest, I haven't used Twisted before, so I was using this an excuse to learn it...lol.

Comment: Ah, I made an assumption that your applications where in Python, and therefore integrating with the logging module would be straightforward. I think it would be silly to use the logging module in this scenario. That answers both your questions. Personally, I would investigate using Syslog-NG http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syslog-ng to fill your need. It is robust and proven. If it truly does not meet your needs, then writing a custom application in Twisted, partly for the sake of learning Twisted, sounds reasonable. Your motivation in solving the problem will outweigh the technology you choose.

Answer (score 0):

Do consider **zeromq**, instead of raw sockets. Its no message broker server, its a library to let you *write* your message passing system. It enables easy cross-platform and language-agnostic communication over TCP, IPC (yes,inter-process!), multicast and other protocols. Simply swap a python component with a C component and it just works as before.

Its the perfect software to satisfy your "..excuse to learn.." ;-)

But the show-stopper would be building it in your Solaris setup. Python bindings are at http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyzmq/2.1.9